# Google Visualization Table Chart - changing column names

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization

How would I go about changing the column names in the Google Table Chart?  The columns names appear as the metrics given (ga:users | ga:sessions | ga:bounceRate) in the query.  I need to have them displayed as: users | sessions | bounceRate.  Do I have to create a new view? Or do some sort of getcolumnLabel and change it?

```
<head>
    <title>Google Charts</title>

    <script>

    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
        g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
        js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>

    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXX'; // obtained from your service account

    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        serverAuth: {
        access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
    });

    var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query:  {
    ids: 'ga:XXX',
    metrics: 'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
    output: 'dataTable'
        }
    });
    data.execute();

    data.on('success', function(response) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits: 0});
    formatter.format(data, 0);
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits: 0, suffix: '%'});
    formatter.format(data, 2);
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('test'));
    table.draw(data);
        });    
    });

    // Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>             
                <div>
                    <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
                    <div id="test"></div>     
                </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, in the future when you ask questions, please make sure you don't have syntax errors in your code samples. You have some extra closing braces that I had to track down and fix before I could run it. Also, make sure everything is properly indented so it's easier to read at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column headers are just the values in the `dataTable` instance, which you're already using in your `success` callback.

To rename them, just do something like this:

```
response.dataTable.cols[0].label = 'Users';
response.dataTable.cols[1].label = 'Sessions';
response.dataTable.cols[2].label = 'Bounce Rate';
```

Also, you may or may not realize that you have a potential race condition in your code. You're loading the Embed API and then doing a query request, and you're also loading the Google Visualization library like so:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
```

While it's unlikely that the Embed API will load and run the query prior to loading the gviz library, it's definitely possible, and if that happens you'll get an error.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.  Are you saying I should be loading the Google Visualization library prior to the Embed API and the query request?  If so, could you please show me an example how to accomplish this?

Comment: You'll want to run the `gapi.analytics.ready` function only after the gviz library is loaded. To do that, look into using the load `callback` option documented here: https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad

Comment: dataTable.setColumnLabel(1, 'Users') did the trick in my case